# Interpolation of time series data in R

Tags: r, plot, interpolation

I'm not sure what i'm missing here, but i'm basically trying to compute interpolated values for a time series; when I directly plot the series, constraining the interpolation points with "interpolation.date.vector", the plot is correct:

```
plot(date.vector,fact.vector,ylab='Quantity')
lines(spline(date.vector,fact.vector,xout=interpolation.date.vector))
```

When I compute the interpolation, store it in an intermediate variable, and then plot the results; I get a radically incorrect result:

```
intepolated.values <- spline(date.vector,fact.vector,xout=interpolation.date.vector)

plot(intepolated.values$x,intepolated.values$y)
lines(intepolated.values$x,intepolated.values$y)
```

Doesn't the lines() function have to execute the spline() function to retrieve the interpolated points in the same way i'm doing it?

Comment: You have to be specific about what's wrong besides your using `plot(intepolated.values$x,intepolated.values$y)` instead of `plot(date.vector,fact.vector,ylab='Quantity') ` the second time, because the results look fine to me.

Comment: Looks fine to me as well.
`lines(spline(date.vector,fact.vector,xout=interpolation.date.vector))` should be the same as 
`lines(intepolated.values)`

Answer (score 1):

For interpolation, I use [approx](http://www.nku.edu/~longa/Rweb/library/base/html/approxfun.html).
Example:

```
inter <- approx(date.vector, fact.vector, xout=interpolation.date.vector)
inter$x # holds x interpolated values, basically interpolation.date.vector 
inter$y # holds y interpolated values
```

The drawback is that it either does linear or constant interpolation.